# multi level cascade inner join select query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I've following table structure 
[image]

I'd like to select post_id from any available data of short_name(country name), name (state table) or region_name. Executing following query true result for region_name but not for short_name(country name), name (state table).

```
select *
from t_post_city
inner join t_region on t_region.region_id = t_post_city.city_id
inner join t_country on t_region.country_id = t_country.country_id
inner join t_states on t_region.province_id = t_states.state_id
where t_country.short_name like %india%
   or t_states.name like %rajasthan%
   or t_region.region_name like %sitapura%
```

Tell me please, where I'm mistaking!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: sorry my query si select * from t_post_city 
inner join t_region on t_region.region_id = t_post_city.city_id 
inner join t_country on t_region.country_id = t_country.country_id
inner join t_states on t_region.province_id = t_states.state_id 
where t_country.short_name like %india% or t_states.name like %rajasthan% or  t_region.region_name like %sitapura%

Comment: It's postgres actually

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from t_post_city
LEFT OUTER join t_region on t_region.region_id = t_post_city.city_id
LEFT OUTER join t_country on t_region.country_id = t_country.country_id
LEFT OUTER join t_states on t_region.province_id = t_states.state_id
 where t_country.short_name like '%india%'
 or t_states.name like '%rajasthan%'
 or t_region.region_name like '%sitapura%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a distinct table expression for each of your three criteria. Write your `OR` logic using `UNION` in SQL:

```
select post_id
from t_post_city
inner join t_region on t_region.region_id = t_post_city.city_id
where t_country.short_name like %india%
t_region.region_name like %sitapura%
union
select post_id
from t_post_city
inner join t_region on t_region.region_id = t_post_city.city_id
inner join t_country on t_region.country_id = t_country.country_id
where t_country.short_name like %india%
union
select post_id
from t_post_city
inner join t_region on t_region.region_id = t_post_city.city_id
inner join t_states on t_region.province_id = t_states.state_id
where t_states.name like %rajasthan%;
```